# How can I create a car mod for GTA: Vice City?

Tags: modding

I am a player of GTA games. I want to create my own car for GTA: Vice City. How do I create a mod that adds a new car to the game?

Comment: I Know about **sanny buider** -  a tool for creating `dff` and `txd` files. but it not works for me. so i am asking this question.

Comment: N.B. that *modding questions are on-topic here*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make a totally new car, you'll first have to model it in 3D in a modelling program. [Blender](https://www.blender.org/) is a reasonable freely-available modelling tool.

Once you've got the model, you need to export it into the `.dff` file format used by Vice City. [This plugin](http://www.gtagarage.com/mods/show.php?id=21598) can export from Blender to `.dff`; you can find plenty of other `.dff` exporters for other modelling tools as well if you search around.

The [G-IMG tool](http://www.gtagarage.com/mods/show.php?id=2077) can be used to edit GTA's archive files and install your custom `.dff` (and associated `.txd`). The `.dff` and `.txd` files exported for the car are the basics needed to get the car in game; the rest allows you to customize and tweak the car.

The [CFG Studio tool](http://projectcerbera.com/tools/cfgstudio2/) can be used to install any custom `handling.cfg` (which is just a text file) parameters for your car. [This car editor](http://www.gta-modding.com/area/index.php?act=view&id=32) can also edit handling and color files for your car.

[This guide](http://projectcerbera.com/gta/3-vc/tutorials/installing-cars) covers the basic steps in more detail.

Comment: thank you and +1 for understand my question and for answer.